# Variables assigned from name range are not updated after running the second time

Tags: excel, vba, variables

```vb
Sub AutoAdd_Data3()
    Dim k As Long, maxSTT As Long, h As Long, dkmang As Long, dongdata As Long, DK_LT_BD As Variant, DK_LT_KT As Variant, _
        DK_DOAN As Variant, DK_LOP_BD As Variant, DK_LOP_KT As Variant, dieu_kien As Variant, dong_cuoi As Variant, TA As Variant, _
        dong_cuoi2 As Variant
    
    dong_cuoi = Sheet2.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    dieu_kien = 0
    k = 0
    h = 0
    
    For TA = ActiveSheet.Index To Sheets.Count
        If Sheets(TA).Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
            Sheets(TA).Select
            DK_LT_BD = Range("DK_TU") '.Value
            DK_LT_KT = Range("DK_DEN").Value
            DK_DOAN = Range("DK_DOAN").Value
            dieu_kien = Sheets(TA).Range("AC3")
            Select Case dieu_kien
                Case "PLKTHH"
                    h = 16
                    dong_cuoi2 = Sheets(TA).Range("V" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                    Range("V" & h & ":" & "V" & dong_cuoi2 + 1).Select
                    Selection.ClearContents
                    DK_LOP_BD = Sheets(TA).Range("DK_LOP_BD").Value
                    DK_LOP_KT = Sheets(TA).Range("DK_LOP_KT").Value
                    For dkkt = 1 To DK_LOP_BD - DK_LOP_KT + 1
                    Sheet2.Select
                    For k = 8 To dong_cuoi
                        If Sheet2.Range("A" & k).Value = DK_DOAN And Sheet2.Range("C" & k).Value >= DK_LT_BD And _
                            Sheet2.Range("C" & k).Value <= DK_LT_KT And Sheet2.Range("D" & k).Value = DK_LOP_BD And DK_LOP_BD >= DK_LOP_KT Then
                            'Range("E" & k).Select
                                Sheets(TA).Range("V" & h) = Sheet2.Range("E" & k)
                            'arrLop(h) = k
                                h = h + 1
                        End If
                    Next k
                    DK_LOP_BD = DK_LOP_BD - 1
                    Next dkkt
            End Select
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This is name range

[image: 1]

Variables assigned from name range are not updated after running the second time, but variables assigned by specific numbers can run the code

Comment: Are you expecting the lines like `DK_LOP_BD = Sheets(TA).Range("DK_LOP_BD").Value` to update the value of the named variable in Excel?

Comment: And what does "variables assigned by specific numbers can run the code" mean?

Comment: e.g: DK_LOP_BD = 54 the code run, but if the variable is assigned name range, the if statement will not execute

Comment: Please try to explain that again. I have no idea what you meant by any of that.

Comment: thank you so much, I found it, cell V7 is text